# Missing output when running system command in perl/cgi file

Tags: perl, command-line, variables, shell, cgi

I need to write a CGI program and it will display the output of a system command:

#### script.sh

```
echo "++++++"  
VAR=$(expect -c " spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST $CMD match_max 
100000 expect \"*?assword:*\" send -- \"$PASS\r\" send -- \"\r\" expect eof ") 
echo $VAR 
echo "++++++"
```

In CGI file:

```
my $command= "ksh ../cgi-bin/script.sh";
my @output= `$command`; 
print @output;
```

Finally, when I run the CGI file in unix, the `$VAR` is a very long string including \n and some delimiters. However, when I run on web server, the output is

```
++++++

++++++
```

So `$VAR` is missing when passing in the web interface/browser.
I know maybe the problem is `$VAR` is very long string.

But anyway, is there anyway to solve this problem except writing the output to a file then retrieve it from browser?

Thanks if you are interested in my question.

Comment: Have you tried running script.sh as the same user the webserver is running as?

Comment: Yes, the output is as aboved
Do you think writing the output to a temporary file then read it in cgi file is a a good way to avoid the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1):

`script.sh` uses several environment variables: `$USER`, `$HOST`, `$CMD` and `$PASS`. The CGI environment will have different environment variables set than a login shell. You may need to set these variables from your CGI script before calling `script.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that.
my $command= "ksh ../cgi-bin/script.sh  $USER@$HOST $CMD ";
But I still get the same output with the missing $VAR

Answer (score 0):

Try finding where commands like expect and ssh that you are calling are on your system and adding their directory paths to the PATH used by your script.
I.e.

```
which expect
```

returns /usr/bin/expect then add the line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin && export PATH
```

near the beginning of the ksh script. During debug you may also want to redirect stderr to a file by appending 2>/tmp/errors.txt to the end of your command since stderr is not shown in the browser.

```
my $command= "ksh ../cgi-bin/script.sh 2>/tmp/errors.txt";
```