# Alternative module of Net::SSH::Expect or how to connect remote server and get the output of command

Tags: perl, module, expect

I want to use Net::SSH::Expect in my unix box but unfortunately, it is not available and I am not able to convince the admin to install any perl module. Do you know how could I connect to a remote server using expect. 
I know that I can archive that by using python but python is also not avai in my unix box.
Second attempt: though I use expect and shell scripting but the output is missing which is my original problem :[Missing output when running system command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553880/missing-output-when-running-system-command-in-perl-cgi-file)

Please advise me any alternative module of Net::SSH::Expect so I can check its availibility in my unix box. Or any other way to connect remote server, execute some command and get the output ?
Million thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need your system administrator to install a module in order for you to run it. You can download and install it locally, and use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) to use it (as discussed in [earlier questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions)).

Alternatively, have you simply tried:

```
my $output = `ssh username@host command arguments`;
```

Comment: Thanks! I try to install local::lib but unsuccessful. :((

The reason I need to use expect because the server will promt user and password subsequently. So I am seeking an alternative way of using ssh and expect.